# Firestore query for profiles that have not been rated yet

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database design question that I can't figure out the best way to solve. I'm making a rating app where a user can rate others' profiles. I need to figure out a way to store which profiles a specific user has rated so the user can't rate the same profile more than once, and then I need to figure out how to query profiles that have not been rated by the current user.

I was hoping to store the current user's ID into a profile's document once it has been rated, but I don't believe I am able to query for documents where the current user's ID does NOT exist.

The only possible solution I have considered is adding each user's ID into a profile's document as a key and then setting the key to true once it's been rated by that specific user, but that really doesn't seem practical with a large amount of users.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to answer your question in firebase. I am not sure, whether farebase is a relational db. If I have to code in RDBMS, I would maintain a separate table like the following

ProfileRater ProfileRatee
Raters uid   Ratee's uid
Raters uid   Ratee's uid

If, storing the data in firebase is similar to jason, you can probably create a new document/collection with the two properties and create objects.

Good Luck!